# Show or Hide History in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am working on a registration form. I want to show and hide my users past registrations using a button.The button should only show or hide registrations that are gone not the upcoming ones This is what I have so far. Pleasssseeee Help.

```
        <div class="Table01">

                    <button id="older">Show Registration History</button>                  


                @foreach (var sm in Model)
                {

                    var tmp = @sm.SeminarNm.Replace("&", "and");


                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 well table-item" align="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-eventtype="@tmp" data-placement="top" title="@tmp">


                        <span class="sortName mid-weight"> @sm.SeminarNm</span>
                        <span class="sortDate alert-info">(ON @string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", @sm.SessionStartDT) IN @sm.SessionCityNm)</span>

                        <div class="row " style="margin-top:10px">
                            @if (@sm.IsEditable == "Y")
                            {
                                using (Html.BeginForm("EditRegister", "App", FormMethod.Post, new { onclick = "showPageLoadingSpinner()" }))
                                {           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                        <input class="btn btn-success " name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Edit" />
                                        <input type="hidden" value="@sm.RegistrantSeq" name="hiddenseq" />
                                        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="cntView" />
                                        <input type="hidden" value="EditRegister" name="cntStage" />
                                    </div>

                                }
                            }
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewRegister", "App", FormMethod.Post))
                {           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col">
                                    <input class="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" type="submit" value="View" />
                                    <input type="hidden" value="@sm.RegistrantSeq" name="hiddenseq" />
                                    <input type="hidden" value="ViewRegister" name="cntStage" />
                                </div>

                            }
                            //                        




                    </div>

                }
                </div>




            </div>



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>

    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function () {
        if (this.id == 'older') {
            $('#child > div').toggle(450);
        }

        $btns.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })


</script>
```

[My Program Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw8Z6.png)

I dont know if I need some sorting javascript function to display only those sessions that are in the past. Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming old registrations are any item with `SessionStartDT` value earlier than current date, you can set an html data attribute on each item's container div indicating whether it is an old item or new item and when user clicks the hide/show button, toggle the visibility of these items.

```
@foreach (var sm in Model)
{
  <div data-old="@(p.SessionStartDT.Date < DateTime.Today.Date)">

      <!-- your existing code for rendering each item goes here -->

  </div>
}
```

And in the javascript part, when the button is clicked, make select the elements who's `data-old` attribute value is `True` (which we set via our C# expression which results in a boolean value) and toggle the visibility.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#older").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("[data-old='True']").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: <div data-old="@(p.SessionStartDT.Date < DateTime.Today.Date)"> This part is not working. I am getting an error:  The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Comment: i think you have a syntax error in your code. I would recommend commenting out/removing everything inside that div (i have in answer) and simply add  an inner div to just print the  `SeminarNm`. Once this is working simply uncomment/add one by one and you will know which part has the problem.

Comment: Sorry, yes I fixed the syntax error. The program works but when I click on the button it does not do anything

Comment: do you have that javascript loaded in that page ? Do you have any other script errors in the page which is preventing this js code to execute ? ( check your browser console). Also check the view source and see it set the correct value for the data attribute. you can also put an alert/console.log('clicked') inside the click event to verify your click event handler is being invoked properly.

Comment: Yes I did that, it goes in the javascript function . Maybe there is something wrong with  $("[data-old='True']").toggle(); ....this line. Can I use something other than data-old ?? even in the <div> ??

Comment: It should work as long as you do not have any script errors. See the working jsbin sample http://jsbin.com/gadevowayu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes I think I am making some mistake in the javascript code. What should I put here:  $("[data-old='True']").toggle();
        }); In the div I have this   <div data-old="(@sm.SessionStartDT < DateTime.Today.Date)">

Comment: what you mean what you should put ? The code i have in the answer /js bin should work

Comment: oh yes it does, sorry. Thanks alot